# Understanding a property of regular CW-complexes

Tags: algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

[image]

I'm studying CW-complexes and regular CW-complexes be a special case . It has a basic property as you can see in lemma $5.5$ in the picture above . I assume you are familiar with CW-complexes . Could you explain the yellow line in the picture above . Invariance of domain just gives me $e^{n-1} \cap \overline{e}^{n}$ is open in $\overline{e}^{n} - e^{n}$ , not $e^{n-1}$

Comment: You have an open subset $W$ of $e^{n-1}\cap \partial e^n$ (i denote $\partial e$ instead of $\dot e$). You can view $W$ as homeomorphic to a subset of $e^{n-1}$ an open $(n-1)$ ball which you can view as an open subset of a $(n-1)$-sphere, or as homeomorphic to an open subset of $\partial e^n$ an $(n-1)$-sphere. The invariance of the domain tells you that if you have a homeomorphism between an open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{S}^n$ and a subset $K$ of $\mathbb{S}^n$ then $K$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^n$. Thus $W$ is open in both $\partial e^n$ and $e^{n-1}$

Comment: What book is this from ?

Comment: A.Rod : Can you explain more clearly ? .

Comment: Olivier Begassat : W.S.Massey homology and cohomology theory : An approach based on Alexander-Spanier Cochains .

Comment: What part of the argument aren't you comfortable with exactly?

Comment: Did you mean we view $(n-1)$ ball as an open subset of $(n-1)$ sphere through a standard map $f$ ? So does you sure that $f$ can be viewed as a embedding map  ?

Comment: To be more specific , I guess your idea as following : the first $e^{n-1} \cap \partial e^{n}$ is open in $\partial e^{n} = S^{n-1}$ , and compose characteristic map $\phi$  with a map $f$ : $e^{n-1} \cap \partial e^{n} \subset e^{n-1} \to U^{n-1} \to S^{n-1}$ then you get $f(\phi)(e^{n-1}\cap \partial e^{n})$ is homeomorphic to $e^{n-1} \cap \partial e^{n}$ on $S^{n-1}$ then $f(\phi)(e^{n-1}\cap \partial e^{n})$ is also open , by continuity $e^{n-1} \cap \partial e^{n}$ is also open in $e^{n-1}$

Comment: Well I guess Olivier Begssat is not as lazy as I am and he completely unfolded the argument below. =)

Comment: Olivier's post is exactly what I want to see .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varphi:S^{n-1}\to K^{n-1}$ be the the attaching map for the cell $e^n$. Recall that $e^{n-1}$ is an open subset of $K^{n-1}$, thus the preimage $P=\varphi^{-1}(e^{n-1})$ is an open subset of $S^{n-1}$. Notice also that $P\neq S^{n-1}$ for compactness reasons, and so, using stereographic projection, we may think of $P$ as an open subset of $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

Since $\varphi$ is injective, and thus induces a homeomorphism onto its image for compactness / Hausdorff reasons, it restricts to a homeomorphism from $P$ to $\varphi(S^{n-1})\cap e^{n-1}$, or $\dot{e}^n\cap e^{n-1}$ in Massey's notation. However, recall that the subspace topology $e^{n-1}$ inherits from $K^{n-1}$ coïncides with the standard topology on $e^{n-1}=D^{n-1}$

Hence, $\varphi$ induces a homeomorphism from $P$ to $\varphi(S^{n-1})\cap e^{n-1}$, a certain subset of $e^{n-1}\simeq D^{n-1}$. In particular, it induces a continuous injection from $P$ to $D^{n-1}$, both open subsets of $\Bbb R^{n-1}$.

By invariance of domain, an injective continuous map between open subsets of $\Bbb R^n$ is open, and hence $\varphi(S^{n-1})\cap e^{n-1}$ is open.